# rendering of radicals

Tags: discussion, bug, mathjax

$$
\frac{\sqrt{3(m-n)^2 n^2}}{2}
$$
This expression is getting correctly rendered here on meta.  I copied and pasted it from math.stackexchange.com.  There, the horizontal line did not extend far enough in either direction, going to just above the middle of the $n$ on the right and failing to cover the $3$ on the left.  The difference between $\sqrt{3x}$ and $\sqrt{3}x$ is crucial, so this is a substantial problem.

---

The question where this expression appears is [Finding integer solutions to $m$ and $n$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/182929/finding-integer-solutions-to-m-and-n).

Comment: A link to the original would be nice.

Comment: @LeonidKovalev: It looks like it might be [Finding integer solutions to $m$ and $n$](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/182929/finding-integer-solutions-to-m-and-n).

Comment: That's the one.

Comment: Perhaps you could attach a screenshot of how it looks on your end, and also mention your browser/OS specs? For what it's worth, the expression renders correctly in both places for me.

Comment: @DylanMoreland : Someone posted a screenshot below that shows exactly what I saw.  I can now report that the problem happens with chrome but not with firefox.

Answer (score 6):

Probably related: I often see long square root signs rendered in three pieces, as below. [Source](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/182869/finding-volume-and-centroid). Chrome 21/Win7.

[image: Broken pieces]

But in the question pointed out by @Michael the left and right pieces are missing altogether:

[image: Missing pieces]

Comment: I too have this issue

Comment: I've seen that recently.

Comment: Your second screen shot is exactly what I saw.

Comment: Are all the other commenters also using Chrome 21?  Also, is the browser zoom set to 100% or are you zoomed in or out?

Comment: @DavideCervone Default zoom (100%) here. I guess I'm going back to FF; Chrome is getting more and more annoying recently.

Comment: I also have issues with square brackets generated using \left[ and \right].

Comment: @LeonidKovalev FF vs. Chrome says nothing as to why the rendering is correct in meta and not in main.

Comment: @EdGorcenski, can you say more about the issue you are having with left and right brackets (and what browser/os and versions)?  Thanks.

Comment: Windows 7 64-bit, Chrome 21.0.1180.79 m.

The upper "limb" on the left/right brackets often does not appear, making the statement $\left[ x \right]$ appear as $\lfloor x \rfloor$.

Comment: I would like further to add that I have tested this on the same Windows 7 64-bit machine with Internet Explorer 9.0.9 and everything renders properly.

Answer (score 1):

MathJax v2.1 should resolve this issue for Chrome users.  Math.SE is now using the beta version of MathJax v2.1, so you should see the correct rendering for square roots (and fraction bars) now.  Please let me know if that is not the case.

Note that if you keep Chrome open continually, you may need to empty the cache and reload the page (or perhaps even restart Chrome) to get the new copy of MathJax.  (MathJax's About box should tell you which version you are getting; make sure all the files in the list show v2.1).

Comment: @EdGorcenski, is there any improvement with the brackets for you in this version?  If not, can you point to a page that exhibits the problem?